# Javascript: array undefined when loading images from a cache

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I've been testing a big of code in JavaScript to make loading an image sequence onto a webpage easier (following the DRY rule). All 32 images load correctly (I can view them in the web developers toolkit when I press F12), however when I try to verify that the images have been added to the Array cache, it returns undefined (implying that none have been added).

JavaScript:

```
var cache = [];

function imgList(base,firstNum,lastNum) {

    var img;
    for(var i = firstNum;i <= lastNum; i++) {
        img = new Image();

        if(i <=9){ var EXT = '000'}
        else if(i <= 99){var EXT = '00'}
        else if(i <= 999){var EXT = '0'}
        else{var EXT = ''}

        img.src = base + "." + EXT + i + ".jpg";
        cache.push(img);
    }

}

imgList("Scene%201/scene%201",1,32);

alert(document.write(cache.length));
```

Comment: `function pad(num) { return ("000"+num).slice(-4);}` - how do you verify? `document.write('<img src="'+cache[25]+'" />')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cache = [];

alert(cache.length);

function imgList(base,firstNum,lastNum) {

    var img;
    for(var i = firstNum;i <= lastNum; i++) {
        img = new Image();

        if(i <=9){ var EXT = '000'}
        else if(i <= 99){var EXT = '00'}
        else if(i <= 999){var EXT = '0'}
        else{var EXT = ''}

        img.src = base + "." + EXT + i + ".jpg";
        cache.push(img);
    }

}

imgList("Scene%201/scene%201",1,32);

alert(cache.length);
```

Works fine...

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1tok6au/)

Comment: Funny, I just solved that issue myself and was writing my answer, deleting the document.write syntax in the alert box. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.